# npm -g @angular/cli (11.2) errors

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to install the latest version of Angular (v11.2) and I getting:-

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@11.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1102.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@11.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@11.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/angular@11.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/update@0.1102.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

and I don't understand why.

I've switched npm to v6.11.3 and tried again. Now I'm getting:-

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v15.8.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I installed node 14.15.5 which includes npm 6.14.11 and re-installed `@angular/cli` and I don't get any warnings.

Comment: Getting this as well. Nice Valentine's day gift of version incompatibilities because who cares about quality of life.

Comment: On Windows, I had to manually install npm, **npm install -g npm@6.14.11**